# Evolution of allowed characters in XML names?

Tags: xml, w3c, standards-compliance

I'm trying to write an XML parser, and I'm getting confused about the `NameStartChar` which, according to the standard is

```
NameStartChar      ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
```

One of the tests that is provided by W3C Conformance Test Suite 20080827, considers the following example as  not-well-formed because the name starts with `#x309a`. Though according to the definition, it should be in the acceptable range of the `NameStartChar`:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY e "<&#x309a;></&#x309a;>">
]>
<doc>&e;</doc>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The disconnect is due to the difference between how XML names were defined originally versus how they were later defined...

### XML 1st through 4th Editions

[**XML 1.0 (Second Edition) errata 20020320, W3C Conformance Test Suite 20020606**](https://www.w3.org/XML/Test/xmlconf-20020606.htm) does indeed include rule `not-wf-sa-140`,

> Character `&#x309a;` is a `CombiningChar`, not a Letter, and so may not
>   begin a name.

However, that rule is based upon [**Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Second Edition), W3C Recommendation 6 October 2000**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006), where the definition of `Name` is based on [`Letter`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Letter):

```
Name ::= (Letter | '_' | ':') (NameChar)*
```

where [`Letter`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Letter) has a definition that excludes [`CombingChar`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-CombiningChar), which includes `#x309A`.

### XML 5th Edition

The definition of [`Name`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) based on [`NameStartChar`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) which you cite,

```
Name ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
```

is from the much more recent [**Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition), W3C Recommendation 26 November 2008**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/).  It does allow `&#x309a;` — see the `[#x3001-#xD7FF]` range above.

---

You should instead use the more recent test suite, [**XML W3C Conformance Test Suite, 27 August 2008**](https://www.w3.org/XML/Test/xmlconf-20080827.html), for your parser work.  There, you'll find a note about this

> Character `&#x309a;` is a `CombiningChar`, not a Letter, ***but as of 5th
>   edition, may begin a name (c.f. `xmltest/not-wf/sa/140.xml`***).

<sup>[***Emphasis added***]</sup>

Comment: thank you but according to the last version of the XML, is  x309a can't be used as a valid namestart? even the rule of the same version is saying something else?

Comment: Yes, as of the 5th edition of the XML standard, `&#x309a;` may begin a name.  Previously, it could not.  I've updated the answer to make this more clear.